# Should I store the state of a variable that depends upon another variable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

**Is it okay to save the state of a dependent variable?**

I am learning Android development through the official Android course. In one of the projects, I came across a line of code that saves the state of a variable that depends on another variable whose state has already been saved. The code is as follows:

> In this code, we have already stored the state of the variable **currentDessertIndex**. Since the value of **currentDessertPrice** and **currentDessertImageId** depends upon the **currentDessertIndex** whenever the recomposition happens, the two variables will be assigned the correct value of even if we do not store the state of those.

```
@Composable
private fun DessertClickerApp(
    desserts: List<Dessert>
) {

    var revenue by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var dessertsSold by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }

    val currentDessertIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }

    var currentDessertPrice by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(desserts[currentDessertIndex].price)
    }
    var currentDessertImageId by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(desserts[currentDessertIndex].imageId)
    }
    ...
}
```

> This is what I think should be the right way to do it.

```
@Composable
private fun DessertClickerApp(
    desserts: List<Dessert>
) {

    var revenue by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var dessertsSold by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }

    val currentDessertIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }

    var currentDessertPrice = desserts[currentDessertIndex].price
    
    var currentDessertImageId = desserts[currentDessertIndex].imageId
    
    ...
}
```

So, what do you suggest? Am I correct or does this invites any isssue?

[Link to the Line of code](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-dessert-clicker/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/dessertclicker/MainActivity.kt#L177)

I changed the way the the state was stored. Now I expect to tell me if I am correct or does this invite any issue.

Comment: The `currentDessertIndex` in the example you linked to actually does nothing. It never get updated, while `currentDessertPrice` and `currentDessertImageId` are getting updated.

Comment: From my understanding of compose, the issue here might be that since `currentDessertPrice` depends on  a stateful variable `currentDessertIndex` , it's value might get changed. but can you be sure that change gets reflected every where `currentDessertPrice` gets used. From my understanding, It would only change the value of `currentDessertPrice` and that would be reflected only when calling it the next time. not where it is already in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you want a dependent state to change only when the state it depends on changes.

```kotlin
var currentDessertPrice = desserts[currentDessertIndex].price
var currentDessertImageId = desserts[currentDessertIndex].imageId
```

However, in the above lines, the dependant states will be calculated every time the composable recomposes which is unnecessary. So, you have to use remember to remember the values between recomposition.

Also, I think that this can be a good use case of [derivedStateOf](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#derivedstateof).

Comment: “Calculated” is a stretch here. Accessing a list element and a property is trivial. Remembering the retrieved value will be at least as expensive as retrieving each time, so I would go with the simpler code and retrieve each time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's generally better to only save the state of independent variables.

If the dependent variables are complex (not in your case), you can save their states too but you'll have to be careful to update them when the independent variable changes. Otherwise you will encounter hard to find bugs where some parts of your composable doesn't update.